# How can I limit page parent dropdown to show only author's own pages?

Tags: wp-admin, author, page-attributes

I'm trying to get the page parent dropdown (in page attributes) to show only pages that have been published by the author of the current page.

This doesn't seem to work :

```
add_filter( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 'mwm_show_only_author_pages_in_attributes' );
add_filter( 'quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args', 'mwm_show_only_author_pages_in_attributes' );

function mwm_show_only_author_pages_in_attributes( $args ) {

    global $post;

    $args['author'] = $post -> post_author;

    return $args;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [source code](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L0) the function wp_dropdown_pages uses [get_pages()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) and this function uses [different attributes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) than WP_Query or get_posts(). It uses **authors** instead of **author**.

Note from the codex:

> authors 
>       (string) Only include the Pages written by the given author(s) 
>       Note: get_posts() uses the parameter 'author' instead of 'authors'.

Comment: Thanks david, I should really look at the source more often.

Comment: No problem, glad to help you.